# No products on site after backup/restore database from one server to another

Tags: magento2, backup, magento2.3.2

I'm trying to copy the database data from my production Magento 2.3.2 site to a local development site.

I created a backup of my production MySQL database with phpmyadmin like in the screenshot below.

[image]

Then on my local server, I created a new database named `magento` and restored my production database (named `ad2f5134_newlive`) into it with `mysql -u root -p magento < ad2f5134_newlive.sql`

Then I updated the URLs in `core_config_data` for my local development site.

The problem is that no products show up on my local development site.  When I go to Catalog > Products in the Admin section, I get this message:

[image]

I checked `catalog_product_entity` on my local development site, and all the products from my production site are in the table.

One thought I had is that it is an indexer problem, so I ran `bin/magento indexer:reindex`.  That gives me the following error:

```
General error: 1449 The user specified as a definer ('ad2f5134_newlive'@'%' does not exist...
```

So my two questions are:

- Why are no products on the site -- even though they are in the database -- and why don't any products show up in the Admin section under Catalog > Products?
- The user `ad2f5134_newlive` is the database user from my production site.  Something in the database must now be telling my local development site to be using the `ad2f5134_newlive` user to run those reindexing queries.  How do I change that user to by my local user?

Comment: I believe you have some procedure which is using the production user go to your selected database in phpmyadmin, what do you have in your Routins tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1** :
for this error, you can try with below process :

1. Run this SQL to generate the necessary ALTER statements

   `SELECT CONCAT("ALTER DEFINER='your-user@host' VIEW ", table_name, " AS ", view_definition, ";") FROM information_schema.views WHERE table_schema='your-database-name';`
2. Copy and run the ALTER statements

Example:

```
UPDATE `mysql`.`proc` p SET definer = 'user@%' WHERE definer='root@%'
```

**Option 2 :**

Create the missing user
If you've found following error while using MySQL database:

The user specified as a definer ('some-user'@'%') does not exist`
Then you can solve it by using following :

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'some-user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'complex-password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Thank you.  I got permission denied errors when I tried to update the view, so I added that user and now it works.